# Unable to launch the zalenium dashboard

Tags: docker, selenium, automation, zalenium

currently I am working on Linux

```
  elgalu/selenium and   dosel/zalenium images are successfully pulled but while running the images by using below command
  # Run     docker run --rm -ti --name zalenium -p 4444:4444 \
      -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
      -v /tmp/videos:/home/seluser/videos \
      --privileged dosel/zalenium start
```

[image: please view the pic]

```
Docker binary already present, will use that one.
Docker version 18.09.0, build 4d60db4
-- LOG 11:29:11:261904322 Ensuring docker works...
-- LOG 11:29:11:313323416 Ensuring docker-selenium is available...
haveged: haveged starting up
Copying files for Dashboard...
```

it was stopped at "copying files for dashboard" and in tmp/videos am able to view few files and container is up and running but unable to view the dashboard(http://localhost:4444/grid/console)

Comment: You need to make sure your `/tmp/videos` directory is empty or with just a few files. If it has too many files, this part will take forever.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
docker run -d -ti --name zaleniums -p 4445:4444 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /tmp/videos:/home/seluser/videos --restart=always --privileged dosel/zalenium start --desiredContainers 3 --videoRecordingEnabled false
```

Comment: yeah i have tried the output looks like                                                                     
 "docker run -d -ti --name zaleniums -p 4445:4444 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /tmp/videos:/home/seluser/videos --restart=always --privileged dosel/zalenium start --desiredContainers 3 --videoRecordingEnabled false
8f6ccdba07059bb1228522489c1922fe12cee4396a3c434a4b187d84bd6791b8"                                
                          ---->zalenium was not started it just ended by giving container id